# How to label only some levels with guide_coloursteps?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

it is my first Question here at Stackoverflow so I hope that the style is correct.

I have a contour plot like in this example:

```
ggplot(faithfuld, aes(x = waiting, y = eruptions, z = 100 * density)) +
  geom_contour_filled(breaks = seq(-4, 4, length.out = 25)) + 
  scale_fill_viridis_d(guide = guide_coloursteps(barwidth = unit(7,"cm"), show.limits = T)) +
  theme( legend.position = "bottom")
```

Unfortunately there is only the possibility to label the whole axis or delete all labels (`label = FALSE`). I would like to have labels for the extreme values and perhaps one in the middle and one between the middle and the borders.

Are there any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 workarounds, we can either rotate the labels using,

```r
theme(legend.position = "bottom",
      legend.text = element_text(angle = 90))
```

Or, we can manually provide the labels,

```r
scale_fill_viridis_d(guide = guide_coloursteps(barwidth = unit(7,"cm"), show.limits = F),
                     labels = c('0','','','','','2','','','','','4')) +
```

Its not elegant, but `labels` argument requires `label` for each `category`.

Comment: Thank you very much. That really solved my problem!